# go generate to substitute statement location

Tags: go

I'm using a policy to add the location of the log statement in code.

Eg. `fmt.Println("main.go:myFunction(): There was an error:", e)`

How would I use go generate to do something like

`fmt.Println("%fn%: There was an error:", e)`

and it will substitute the name of the go file, the enclosing function name, and the line number?

Comment: You would have to come up with a heuristic which identifies "log statements" which require function names from ordinary print statements. Don't do that. If this is your approach to logging you are doomed anyway.

Comment: Actually I don't want to make that distinction.  I just want to replace a predefined string (say %fn%) with the file name, method name, and position in file.  Would that even be the use case for go generate?

Comment: No, that is not a usecase for go generate. Write a logging function which examines the stack trace.

Comment: Why not just use a logger with `Lshortfile` flag set?

Comment: This gives me a nice idea of using `go generate` to really remove logging lines by level before compilation :)

Answer (score 4):

Package [runtime](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/) and [Caller()](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Caller) can help here

```
  1 package main
  2 
  3 import (
  4     "fmt"
  5     "runtime"
  6 )
  7 
  8 func Trace () (file string, funcName string, line int, ok bool) {
  9     pc, file, line, ok := runtime.Caller(1)
 10     f := runtime.FuncForPC(pc)
 11     return file, f.Name(), line, ok
 12 }
 13 
 14 func myFunc () {
 15     fmt.Println(Trace())
 16 }
 17 
 18 func main() {
 19     fmt.Println(Trace())
 20     myFunc()
 21 }
```

output:

```
/prog.go main.main 19 true
/prog.go main.myFunc 15 true
```